# default lockout asp.identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using the standard Asp.net Identity framework, Ver 2.0. Is there any way to have a DEFAULT lockout set when the user registers for the first time? Our application requires that on registration, a user needs to be **locked out after 48 hours**. This needs to be **automatic** to avoid unnecessary admin headaches?

I am aware of the following settings, but these just enable not activate the features:

```
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true; // Enables ability to lockout 
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: I've added an answer, but I just re-read this and I'm not entirely sure if you really mean for the account to lock out after 48 hours or be locked out for the first 48 hours. If it's the former, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Hi Kirk. Thanks. We offer up information to a niche industry that users register for and pay for a once off access. This period is 48 hours. So after registration they only have 48 hours to access their purchased information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the lockout mechanism is meant to use like that. But I would like to suggest another solution anyway.

I think the easiest way is to extend ApplicationUser with a CreatedDateTime field that is set when the user is created (registers).

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

When a user logs in just check `appUser.CreatedDateTime.AddDays(2) < DateTime.Now`

As a bonus you can track when the user registered.

Comment: Hi Ruard, thanks for this. I will implement this and give feedback. And with the registration date recorded I can just periodically run an SP to clean out expired registrations.

Comment: Hi Ruard, thanks. This worked like a charm! I did up vote, but don't have enough status yet.